# Where can I find the latest open source Base Classes used in Mac OS X like NSMutableDictionary, NSString, NS****,

Tags: xcode, macos, open-source, nsobject, base-class

do you know some links where I can browse the source codes of base classes used in Mac OS X? I already have this [link](http://svn.gna.org/svn/gnustep/libs/base/branches/reorg/Source/) which I found very useful but based from what I encountered lately (when using NSCache) it seems that it's not the latest source code.

When I used the objectForKey: of NSCache, [NSCache cache:willEvictObject:] is called inside it. But based on the code in this [link](http://svn.gna.org/svn/gnustep/libs/base/branches/reorg/Source/), there is no way that cache:willEvictObject will be called when objectForKey: is called. I need to know what really is the behavior of objectForKey method of NSCache.

Knowing the source code of classes of APIs helps greatly in debugging, optimization, and creating subclass from base classes.

Comment: "Knowing the source code of classes of APIs helps greatly in debugging, optimization, and creating subclass from base classes." No it wouldn't. There's a thing called "abstraction".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> do you know some links where I can browse the source codes of base classes used in XCode?

(Minor corrections beforehand: not "in Xcode", Xcode has nothing to do with these, they aren't part of Xcode but the part of the OS X and iOS SDKs. Also, it's spelled Xcode with a lowercase 'c'.)

Well, to the topic: no. The Cocoa frameworks are closed-source. One exception is CoreFoundation of which Apple provides the source code on http://opensource.apple.com , but Foundation and other frameworks aren't released publicly.

Comment: (Thanks for the correction. I changed the word XCode to word Mac OS X. Is it right?)

This link: http://svn.gna.org/svn/gnustep/libs/base/branches/reorg/Source/ 
has open source of basic NSObject subclasses. Though not latest, it gives a big clue on the behavior of a specific NS*** class, but the original is still better and helps avoids wasting time analyzing an NS*** class using black box. 

I currently using the link and it helps me a lot, but when I encountered a behavior that contradicts to what the source code in the link said, I found it hard to think what should be the right solution.

Comment: @xuwicha: that's the source code of GNUStep, not Cocoa, which is what you're using in Mac OS X. Cocoa is not open source.